# What rights go with a paid subscription?

Tags: online

When a platform has the right to kick you out as they deem fit, without any evidence why they did it, does that change if you have a paid?

Because this is going on with me. I'm on a platform where you can post stories. I'm fully aware of the rules and I feel like I haven't posted any content that violated the rules. The platform is free but if you don't want ads and stuff, you can buy a subscription to be a member - and I paid 40 dollars for that. Almost 2 weeks ago, I got an email saying that they took down my work but nothing further. My account seemed to be lost as well but I never got any emails about that. When I asked what I did wrong, I never got an answer. It's been 2 weeks now and I've been ignored or asked to send in a ticket for my problem. I obviously already did that, but the tickets stay unanswered and all other company help options send me to open a ticket again, which gets me back to the beginning again. If I truly have other opinions than they have, and I have violated the rules in their eyes, I feel they can show that to me. But right now, I don't know anything about why I can't log in. The autoreply email only says that I MIGHT have violated the rules and therefore MAY not be able to log in. I don't know what to do and I feel it's all very unfair.

Answer (score 3):

> When a platform has the right to kick you out as they deem fit, without any evidence why they did it, does that change if you have a paid?

It depends on the purpose of payment and the terms & conditions it triggers.

Your description reflects that payment entitles the user to have no ads "and stuff" (?). Payment does not necessarily entitle the user to continued access, diligence from customer service, or other features.

Without fully knowing the platform's terms & conditions regarding payment it is impossible to identify what obligations (other than not displaying advertisements) your payment creates on the platform. The information you provide here is insufficient for assessing whether you have a viable claim such as *fraud* or *breach of contract*.

On the other hand, the platform's apparent arbitrariness and lack of response might support a finding of *unfair or deceptive practices* if the platform does not honor or proportionally reimburse your payment. Many jurisdictions have legislation prohibiting practices which are unfair, deceptive, or unconscionable (example: [MCL 445.903](http://www.legislature.mi.gov/(S(e0qmtqrce1xiajh5wt2w5opw))/mileg.aspx?page=getobject&objectname=mcl-445-903-amended&query=on)). Oftentimes statutory law establishes an agency in charge of addressing customers' complaints.

Comment: Hello, "And stuff" is you can choose color theme and add more books also in an offline file. There aren't any extra terms and conditions except for the normal ones. So they can kick you out whenever they deem fit and they'll try to let you know about it. But I feel that is wrong when I have put money in there and have no proof of why I am removed. This was they can take money and just remove someone.

Comment: @Suzanne "*I have put money in there and have no proof of why I am removed*". You might have been scammed. If the platform denies you a prorated reimbursement, you might want to file a complaint/grievance with the agency that addresses unfair/deceptive practices in your jurisdiction.

Comment: And you can also save more coins to buy their paid books (normally the reads are for free). That's pretty much it. I'm just mostly irritated about the way im being ignored and not even about the money itself. (Sorry English isn't my mother tongue so I will have typos in my texts)

Comment: It's actually quite a big company with a lot of users so I can't imagine they are scamming people (it's Wattpad) but I have looked everywhere for other terms for the paying service (premium user) and I can not find it anywhere. When I ask about it they keep silent. And thank you for your answers because I could not find something anywhere.

Comment: @Suzanne "* I'm just mostly irritated about the way im being ignored and not even about the money itself*". I hear you. But if you intend to go after the company, demanding *and* being denied (even in the form of nonresponse) a prorated reimbursement is likelier to prompt the [Ontario consumer protection agency](https://www.ontario.ca/page/consumer-protection-ontario) to proceed against the company than if you only mention the irritation the company's pattern of evasion understandably causes you. "*Sorry English isn't my mother tongue*".Your English is good and your post is quite intelligible.

Comment: Obviously I'm not going to fly over to Canada to sue them. I just wanted to bluff a little with great knowledge. But I guess I don't have anything. Thank you.

Comment: @Suzanne "*I'm not going to fly over to Canada to sue them*". At least at first glance, I don't see in the [page for filing a complaint](https://www.ontario.ca/page/filing-consumer-complaint) or in [Ontario Consumer Protection Act](https://www.ontario.ca/laws/statute/02c30) a requirement that the consumer be located in, or travel to, Canada. The Ministry of Consumer and Business Services Act is the entity that would enforce the Consumer Protection Act pursuant to this matter.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into this. I've actually tried to "intimidate" them with it, but I again got the same auto-reply and they just closed my case without any answers again. It really makes me wonder why they can't just answer me when I ask them to tell me what I did wrong. It's not that hard of a question in my eyes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The public [Terms of Service](https://policies.wattpad.com/terms/) states that

> Wattpad may change, terminate, or restrict access to any aspect of the
> Services, at any time, without notice

and

> we will also terminate a user’s account if the user is determined to
> be a repeat infringer

and

> We may suspend or terminate your account or cease providing you with
> all or part of the Services at any time and for any reason we deem
> appropriate. We will make reasonable efforts to notify you by the
> email address associated with your account or the next time you
> attempt to access your account.

It is possible that the paid versions offer you more protection against cancellation.

The final clause regarding notification seems to have been satisfied, though not to your satisfaction (you did get notification that you were terminated). There is no indication that you get to argue with them over a termination; they basically say "Sue us in Ontario". They are not required to justify their decision to you, but if you sue them in Ontario, it's *possible* that the court will ask why they did so. Since the contract allows arbitrary termination, their reason would mostly be irrelevant, since it is their right. The specifics of the premium contract would matter: I don't see what $40 would correspond to, but maybe a year's subscription paid in advance. In that case, because it saves you some money to pay in advance, there is probably a clause about cancellation and refunds that doesn't work to your benefit.

Comment: I'm not sure I get all the legal terms, because I'm not familiar with that at all. But I actually have never gotten an email I was terminated. Only that a few of my books were taken down (which I'm not agreeing to, but that's not my point here) but I've never heard about my account (which I also use to read). Only an auto-reply that said I may not be able to log in because of my terminated books which seems a little vague to me.

Comment: Plus the fact that I've been emailing them for 2 weeks and get no response except for the same auto-reply 3 times that's completely not answering my questions at all is beyond frustrating.

Comment: And I don't know, it just seemed logical to me that when money is involved, other rules apply. Just like a webshop can say put their rules on their site but sometimes other rules apply by law. I feel they can't just throw you out without any reason if you've paid them. Yes, their reason is that my books were violating their rules to which I've asked them to tell me what specifically wasn't right about my books, but they're not telling me. In the meantime, I've contacted google play who is the one I send my money to.

Comment: Plus, it also says in the terms and conditions that wattpad is a free service. The terms and conditions for the premium (paid) account aren't different, they send you to the same rules. That's why I thought I could maybe use other rules, given by law when there's a payment involved. I hope I explain myself well enough.